# what is best way to use trained tensorflow in java

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, jython

I am coding UI by `javaFx` in `eclipse` 
because I can only use java, no python, no c.

Now I try to use trained `tensorflow` file in this UI. (this `tensorflow` file is under python)

I am looking for several ways (`API`, `jython`, `TCP/IP`) but I am not sure which one is best.

Please write your opinion which has more advantages or fewer disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two ways for that,

1. `tensorflow-serving` which uses `grpc` to connect from java to the serving server, making it independent of any language. Look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) for details.
2. Use `tensorflow` `java` API. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java/) and [Here](https://github.com/sumsuddin/TensorflowObjectDetectorJava) is an example of using object detection model in native java program.

Now, `tensorflow-serving` is the preferred way to go, as there are several advantages. Serving is heavily optimized for speed and resource management like GPU. It also stacks multiple requests (if there is too many) and then processes them in a batch which utilizes the GPU efficiently.

Comment: FYI: Additional samples in: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java/

Comment: thanks, @ash I forgot the official demo. Added now.